# How do I fill this area with inclined parallel lines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have achieved the following:

[image]

with the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \coordinate (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate (D) at ($(A)!.5!(C)$);
  \coordinate (E) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);

  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
  \begin{scope}
  \clip (A) rectangle (8,-8);
  \draw (D) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}
  \clip (A) rectangle (8,8);
  \draw (C) let \p1 = ($(B) - (C)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  \end{scope}  

  \begin{scope}
  \clip (A) rectangle (8,8);
  \draw (E) let \p1 = ($(B) - (E)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  \end{scope}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now do I fill the area like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[pattern=north east lines] let \p1 = ($(B) - (A)$) in (A) arc(180:360:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/4})
  arc(180:0:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/4}) arc(0:180:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/2});
  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[pattern=north east lines] (A) 
  arc(180:360:2)  arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4);
  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimized code. But can you also provide a solution with my code.

Comment: @subhamsoni You can add `\path[pattern=north east lines] let \p1 = ($(B) - (A)$) in (A) arc(180:360:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/4})
  arc(180:0:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/4}) arc(0:180:{veclen(\x1,\y1)/2});` to your code (after adding `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}`).

Comment: @subhamsoni Any attempt to fill the fragments rather than just one path will lead to an output which is not very compelling at least on some viewers because you will see little gaps.