# Grid in pattern in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern, sumatrapdf

Referring to the answer in [How do I fill this area with inclined parallel lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/485471/how-do-i-fill-this-area-with-inclined-parallel-lines/485473#485473) , the pattern is generated with grid lines as well. I am not able to understand the behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[pattern=north east lines] (A) arc(180:360:2) arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have highlighted once cell in the grid for reference:

[image]

[image]

With suggestion from Phelype Oleinik, updated code looks like the below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{large north east lines}{%
\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}
{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}% 
{% 
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}% 
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}% 
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{31pt}{31pt}}% 
\pgfusepath{stroke}% 
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[pattern=large north east lines] (A) arc(180:360:2) arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates the below output (still non-satisfactory):

[image]

Comment: Try printing the document. I think this is an issue of the PDF viewer

Comment: As JouleV said this happens because of the rendering. However, the rendering looks like this because the `patterns` library draws one “tile” of the pattern and replicates that tile in the picture. You can increase the tile size to fit the whole picture.

Comment: The same optic illusion shows up with adobe reader and sumatra pdf

Comment: @BambOo I am using Sumatra PDF. Which PDF viewer should I use in this case

Comment: @subhamsoni I have Okular and Evince installed and neither shows the tiling. Try adding this to your preamble: `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{large north east lines}{\pgfqpoint{-1pt}{-1pt}}{\pgfqpoint{4pt}{4pt}}{\pgfqpoint{3pt}{3pt}}%
{%
  \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}%
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}%
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{31pt}{31pt}}%
  \pgfusepath{stroke}%
}%` then use `large north east lines` instead. I'm not sure this will work (mainly because I don't understand that code and my viewer doesn't show the tiling).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - I updated my question with the code. The output is still unsatisfactory.

Comment: @subhamsoni my guess is if adobe shows it you have litlle hope to make it look better without some clever tweaking

Comment: @BambOo - Adobe also have the same output/behavior.

Comment: @subhamsoni What you see in the other picture is a different problem. The problem now is that you are trying to print a continuous diagonal line in a screen with a finite amount of pixels. Try and draw a grid with a diagonal line through it, then fill the squares which the line touches. You won't get a straight line. I think the tiling issue can be solved, but the ragged line issue is viewer-dependent and off-topic. For instance, this is what I get at 75% zoom with [Okular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvwZK.png) and with [Evince](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtwYh.png).

Answer (score 4):

The reasons why people want to use patterns is that they are easy to use and are fast. If you are not happy with the result because it does not look good on your viewer you can always use a simple foreach loop. This takes longer and requires a bit more effort but should look good on any viewer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[clip] (A) arc(180:360:2) arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4); 
  \foreach \X in {0,0.25,...,12}
  {\draw (\X-6,-2) -- ++ (45:15);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Even though you may not easily speed up the compilation time, making the thingy more easy to use is rather straightforward with `path picture`s. Hatching the area then becomes as simple as saying

```
\draw[Subham pattern] (A) arc(180:360:2) arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4);
```

Here is the code that defines and used `Subham pattern`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfkeys{/Subham/.cd,
grid/.style={draw=gray!50,thin},
distance/.initial=4mm,
distance/.code={\pgfkeys{/Subham/distance=#1}}
}
\tikzset{Subham pattern/.style={/utils/exec=\pgfkeys{/Subham/.cd,#1},
path picture={
\path[/Subham/grid] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding
box.south west)$),\n1={int(\x1/\pgfkeysvalueof{/Subham/distance})},
\n2={int(\y1/\pgfkeysvalueof{/Subham/distance})},
\n3={sqrt(2)*max(\x1,\y1)} in 
foreach \XX in {0,...,\n1}
{ 
([xshift=\XX*\pgfkeysvalueof{/Subham/distance}]path picture bounding box.south west)
-- ++ (45:\n3)
}
foreach \YY in {1,...,\n2} {
([yshift=\YY*\pgfkeysvalueof{/Subham/distance}]path picture bounding box.south west)
-- ++ (45:\n3)
};
}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \draw[Subham pattern] (A) arc(180:360:2) arc(180:0:2) arc(0:180:4); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This has several additional advantages since you can change the style at will as well as the density and you can easily adjust the hatch angle and so on.